# Javascript parse a page for find hex color values

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, hex

in my project i need a function for find all hex color values into a webpage (like #FFDD600, #999, etc).
In the past to do the same thing I used php class "PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser", but now I need that # research is carried out ​​in javascript or jquery.

For a study I need to catalog some websites registering the colors used.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the use case? You have not provided much information , very little in fact, making this a very poor quality question

Comment: Are you trying to search for it within the content of a page? Within the HTML tags? Have you actually tried anything yourself?

Comment: I see you edited your question, adding some very invaluable information. Be specific, provide code, provide example case.

Comment: I tried something but I could not find anything. I need to know all the colors used within a web page outside of html tags. I have to catch all # and retrieve the value hex complete. Thanks

Comment: @almal catch colors from what?. If you can't even explain your objective in more than a few words you are not going to get any help. You need to make people understand the complete objective

Comment: "hex color values" at element style ? , or within text of document ? Thanks

Comment: I'm asking for advice because I do not know how to move, I have no code to post, I told you what I used to do it in php but do not know the method in javascript, I do not think it a strange question it so generic, I just need to know if anyone can help me advising a method to extract from a web page all the possible hex values ​​for the colors used (look for # each character regardless of any connected, as if the html code was a long string of text). In any case, thank you for taking the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will fetch an url and parse it as text for all hex values, and put them into current page body.

You can check it out here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fhxutsom/4/)

Though it will be somewhat limited due to cross-origin policy.

```
$.ajax({
    url: ENTER_URL_HERE,
    success: function (data) {
        var hexCodes = $("html").html().match(/#[a-fA-F0-9]{6}|#[a-fA-F0-9]{3}/g);
        $("body").html("");
        $.each(hexCodes, function () {
            $("body").append("<p>" + this + "</p>");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't think I would trust this much.  A lot of colors come from linked CSS files, or maybe even script files.  Even if you parsed those, due to the cascading nature of CSS, you can't really tell what colors are being *used* on the page without having a full understanding of how CSS works.  You'd really need to hook into an HTML engine to make this work accurately.

Comment: @MikeChristensen Well, OP wrote "as if the html code was a long string of text"

Comment: Yea, it's completely unclear what's being asked here.  They mentioned a PHP based HTML parser, which might do something similar to what you wrote.  They also said their goal is "...to catalog some websites registering the colors used." - If that's the goal, I think running the code above on *any* modern website will result in wildly inaccurate results, unless all the styles are inlined or something.